# Is Canadian TRV open to visit visas at this point?

Tags: visas, canada, nigerian-citizens

Please I want to know if its possible for me to apply for TRV at this point for visit visa applications for Canada.
I have travel history for most African nations (5 countries) and I am from Nigeria. Is it possible I apply at this point?

Comment: Welcome to TravelSE. Have you tried searching https://travel.gc.ca/travel-covid/travel-restrictions/wizard-start? Are you fully vaccinated?

Comment: "Yes", but unless you have some kind of urgency, the backlog is ridiculously long.